# Does SquishIt reminify and bundle the css and js files on every page request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, squishit

I am using SquishIt for bundling and minification of css and js files in a asp.net mvc2 application. I want to know will SquishIt reminify and bundle the files  on every page request. Does this not impact the page performance times and response times?

Can anyone help me to know more details about the above.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, bundles are cached the first time they are rendered.